# Responsive and flexible CSS background-image

Tags: css

I wanted to fit on my image based on the resolution but there all on the style code.

Usually we set max-width on `img` tag. but this time how it is possible to do it responsive with any device.

```
<ul class="ch-grid">
    <li>
        <div class="ch-item ch-img">
            <div class="ch-info"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css code below

```
 .ch-grid {

     text-align: center;
     min-width: 100%;
 }

 .ch-grid li {
     width: 620px;
     height: 620px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0px;
 }
 .ch-item {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     position: relative;
     cursor:vertical-text;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 13px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 }
 .ch-img {
     background-image: url(http://s5.favim.com/orig/51/camera-dress-girl-hair-sky-Favim.com-469861.jpg);
     background-position:50% 50%;
     background-size: cover;
 }
 .ch-info {
     position:absolute;
     background: url(http://s5.favim.com/orig/51/camera-dress-girl-hair-sky-Favim.com-469861.jpg) D9E8FC;
     background-position:50% 50%;
     width: inherit;
     height: inherit;
     border-radius: 50%;
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
     -o-transform: scale(0);
     -ms-transform: scale(0);
     transform: scale(0);
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 }
```

Check on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ty7K/)** for more information.

Comment: What do you mean by _responsive with any device_?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to make it responsive to different screen sizes. You need to use media queries. Check this post from CSS-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I meant it will be fluid with the screen size